# RxJava - retrieving entry in Observable in second flatMapSingle

Tags: rx-java2, vert.x, vertx-verticle

We have a vertx verticle which receives an id and uses it see if an entity with the id exist in a database. It contains the following logic:

```
if (itemFound) {
  e.onNext(item_which_was_found)
}
else {
  e.onNext(null);
}
```

Another verticle has an Observable which processes a list of id's. It uses `rxSend` to pass each id in the list to the first verticle to do the database lookup:

```
Observable<Object> observable = ...
observable.flatMapSingle(id -> {
  return rxSend(VERTICLE_1_ADDRESS, id);
})
.flatMapSingle ( i ->
{ 
  // Logic dependent on if item was found
)
.subscribe();
```

With the above, it is easy to handle cases where the entity associated with the id was found in the database, because the first vertcle, in `onNext()`, returns the entity. The question is for the second case, when no entity exists and first verticle returns `onNext(null)`. In this case, how is it possible to retrieve, in the second `flatMapSingle`, the item in the observable which is currently being processed (that is, the `id` which has no associated database entity) ? Or is there a better way to structure the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your observable definition to:

```
Observable<Object> observable = observable();
observable.flatMapSingle(id -> {
  return rxSend(VERTICLE_1_ADDRESS, id).flatMap(i -> {
    // Logic dependent on if item was found
    // id is visible here
  });
}).subscribe();
```

Then the `id` will be visible to your second lambda.